# Apache ./configure can't find pcre-config script

Tags: installation, apache-http-server

I'm trying to install Apache on Red Hat. It's a system I don't have full control over (my sysadmins have given me a directory to work in). So I've downloaded, configured, and installed APR, APR-Util, and PCRE, in addition to Apache 2.4.7.

I ran the following for APR:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apr/
make
make install
```

Received the warning to remember to run

```
libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib
```

I changed that to

```
libtool --finish /u01/app/apache/apr/lib/
```

and it said it installed the Libraries in that location

Similarly, for APR-Util, ran:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin
make
make install
```

Told me the Libraries were installed in /u01/app/apache/apr-util//lib

Next, PCRE:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/pcre/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin --with-apr-util=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/bin
make
make install
```

So far, no problems. Now I try to configure apache

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apache247/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin --with-apr-util=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/bin --with-pcre=/u01/app/apache/pcre/bin
```

It finds APR and APR-Util, but of course, I get the error "Did not find pcre-config script at /u01/app/apache/pcre/bin". Why, I don't know, as the file is there at that location. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it by specifying the full path to the pcre-config file.  In other words, instead of:

```
--with-pcre=/u01/app/apache/pcre/bin
```

I did:

```
--with-pcre=/u01/app/apache/pcre/bin/pcre-config
```

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: On Debian the latest version is called `pcre2-config`, so your config command would be `--with-pcre=/usr/bin/pcre2-config`

Comment: On minimalist centos image, I had to export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_pcre2-config_binary> and use --with-pcre=true option for compiling httpd so that I get here : https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/af558302645384b998333f214d0af37cb3a4ff26/configure.in#L226

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell script and thus it must begin with #!/path/to/interpreter . The most probable cause of your problem is, that this path is bad. For example it is #!/bin/perl although your perl is in /usr/bin. Check this, if it is not ok, fix it manually and retry.

Comment: Uggh, since I'm not a PERL programmer, I'll ask your indulgence.  I found perl in usr/bin, not /bin.  How do I "fix it manually".

Comment: for example, I tried ./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apache247/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin --with-apr-util=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/bin --with-pcre=#!/usr/bin/ /u01/app/apache/pcre/bin and get -bash: !/usr/bin/: event not found

Comment: It was only an example. It isb't probably a perl script. Is this path ok or not? From your error message I see that it is really bad. This seems to be a really dirty error message, with some exotic redhat flavour.

Comment: the path to the pcre-config script is good.  I see that file on the file system.  All of the paths I'm using are good, as far as I can tell, as I see all the files on the file system.

Comment: Nooo! I see. This --with-pcre option shouldn't begin with #! !!! That is the pcre-config script in your pcre/bin ! Please vote up my help, ask on stackoverflow what is an interpreter and what is this #! on the beginning of some script files, vote up their useful answers too, and come back.

Comment: I guess I don't see.  I started the --with-pcre option without the #! initially.  I only tried it the wrong way as I was trying to figure out what to do with the #!.  My original question shows how I tried it initially, and that was without the #!.  Where do I use the #!?  I'll gladly upvote, but I'm no closer to understanding than I was in the first place.

Comment: This is what you should ask on stackoverflow. The answer is simple. I gladly help but I want to see your wish to learn.

Comment: I asked this question on SO, and got sent here.  There are 30000 questions about #!.  You seriously expect me to go through them all?  I would expect the Apache docs to mention needing an interpreter, but they don't.  Sorry, but you've been much less than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Installed pcre-8.37 from pcre.org .os is rhel 7.3 and httpd 2.4.23.After installing pcre there was no need to show the path explicitly

Comment: httpd 2.4.25 still needs to specify the path to the pcre-config script, not the directory. e.g. it's --with-pcre=/home/ubuntu/pcre-8.39/pcre-config

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not using pcre2. download and compile pcre, try re-run.